# How to get multiple output from single pom using maven?

Tags: maven

We have a module A, and we want to build a two jar's and a war  using this module. Files in this module having cyclic dependencies , so we cannot make multiple module. is there any way to do like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea. One of Maven's golden rules is: one pom, one output.

There are obviously exceptions to this, but I highly recommend that you stick with the rule mentioned above. It is going to make your life easier down the road.

The answer is not to continue with the cyclic dependencies, but to fix them. If you have cyclic dependencies, break them apart. I am not even sure that you really have cyclic dependencies, at least not in the reactor, as Maven won't allow it.